# Simulate experiment actions from external service

Tags: smarttarget, api, experiment

I would like to ask if it's possible to simulate the visit and the conversion of an experiment from an external service. That is, when my page renders, invoke a call to increase the visit or simulate the intermediate link used by SDL to add a new conversions. How SmartTarget generate data parameter in intermediate link? If yes, how could it be done? I have seen there is a api "smarttarget_api_extension.jar" but I can't find any documentation about it.

Thanks a lot for you help!!

Sergio.-

Comment: There are a couple of different approaches, so let me ask you this: do you want to keep using whatever analytics system is currently configured (e.g. Google Analytics) and just increase the views and conversions artificially? Or are you simply looking to generate fake/controlled statistics for viewing purposes (e.g. when a user views an Experiment, you control how many views and conversions it reports having)?

Comment: It could be the first one. I would like to know how I can increase a view or a conversion.

Comment: I see. Java or .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track views and conversions using the `AnalyticsManager` in the `com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics` package. You do that by calling `AnalyticsManager.getConfiguredAnalyticsManager()` and then calling either `trackView` or `trackConversion` on it.

As you might expect, you will need to pass in some parameters. The first being the `ExperimentDimensions` - which holds all of the information regarding the Experiment being tracked and the Component Presentation it is showing - and the second is a map of any additional metadata that you wish to pass to the configured analytics provider. That map can be created with the default values by calling `AnalyticsMetaData.fromRequest(request, request.getSession())` (where request is the current `HttpServletRequest`).

To create the `ExperimentDimensions`, you can simply call the default constructor. Be sure to then call all of the setter methods available on it (setExperimentId, setRegion, setComponentId, etc.), with whatever data you want to use.